# How to create a sub dataframe with only objects datatypes?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to create a sub-dataframe with only the columns which are obect data types:

```
df=df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns

Returns error: AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'df'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using the python file name as `pandas.py` please change it and it will fix the error.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you please be more explicit? thanks

Comment: What is the file name of this code which you saved and running?

Comment: I am not sure I understand file name in this context.

Comment: Iam sorry, you are trying to write the code in a file and run right if I am correct, what is the file name you are using to save this code and run ?